# representing multiple numbers by a single number?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

**Is it possible to represent two numbers by a single number such that we can get both numbers back from it?**

This wouldn't be possible because if two numbers $a$ and $b$ are represented by $x$ then $a$, $b$ and $c$ can be represented as $x$ and $c$ and further as some number $y$, and so on,

Now, $2^5 3^2$ ie. $288$ is a representative of $5$ and $2$ as we can easily get $5$ and $2$ by prime factorization of $288$, so can't any amount of number be represented by a single number in this manner,

for example, a single number to represent a triangle completely

Comment: Reworded, you ask if there is a bijection between $\Bbb N^n$ and $\Bbb N$ (*or between $\Bbb R^n$ and $\Bbb R$ or whichever other context you are working in*).  The answer is yes (*for the infinite examples*).

Comment: @JMoravitz so two numbers can be reresented as one?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The method you have already used can be adopted to represent lots of numbers by a single number.

For example, if you have integer coordinates $(a,b),(c,d),(e,f)$ for the vertices of a triangle, then the single number 
$$2^a3^b5^c7^d11^e13^f$$
represents the triangle unambiguosly.

I see this is virtually the same as the answer of @Matthew Daly but I am allowing negative integers as well to produce a representation by rational numbers.

Answer (score 3):

You can represent any finite data structure (including lists of integer numbers) using a string of
characters in some standard format such as [JSON](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON). You can then interpret
the binary bit string  representation of this JSON
character string as the binary representation of a positive integer.

A key advantages of this approach is that it has no
need of the use of prime number factorization and it
can be represent **any** finite data structure and
not just lists of numbers. The OP did **not** specify
what kind of representation **must** be used, but
only gave a simple prime factorization example to
ask about its feasability.

Answer (score 2):

You are correct that we can "encode" any finite list (of known length) of non-negative integers as a singe non-negative integer by the injection $$(a,b,c,...)\mapsto2^a3^b5^c...$$

Of course, this is taking advantage of the factorability of non-negative integers. You couldn't use the same mapping to encode real numbers, obviously.